# OWA HTTPS login issue

Tags: exchange, outlook-web-app

I have a server running Exchange 2013 as well as OWA and when I try to access it via the browser using server.domain/owa, something automatically decides to use HTTPS.

The problem is that OWA uses a URL like

```
logon.aspx?replaceCurrent=1&url=http%3a%2f%2fserver.domain%2fowa
```

to redirect after the login has completed, but as you may notice, the URL used to redirect is an http address and not an HTTPS address. This problem causes the login window to keep reappearing.

Multiple browsers suffer from this issue, so I wonder if this problem is browser- or server- related. When I explicitly use https://server.domain/owa it works as expected.

Comment: Why don't you configure your server to reject a non-secure http connection?  If it happens across multiple browsers ITS NOT A BROWSER problem.

Comment: If I enable "Require SSL" I get a blank screen when going to the server.domain/owa URL. Then it only works if I explicitly specify https://server.domain/owa.

Comment: When I use server.domain/owa as the URL, it appears to first go to http://server.domain/owa and then it automatically redirects to https://server.domain/owa.

Comment: I was able to find these [instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975341) within 5 minutes of looking.  Why exactly don't you want that redirection to happen?

Comment: That does not describe the problem I'm having. I do not want the default web site to redirect to OWA. The redirection happening is not the problem. The generated URL is. It becomes https://server.domain/owa/auth/logon.aspx?replaceCurrent=1&url=http<AN s IS MISSING HERE>%3a%2f%2fserver.domain%2fowa whereas it should be https://server.domain/owa/auth/logon.aspx?replaceCurrent=1&url=https%3a%2f%2fserver.domain%2fowa

Comment: [this](http://www.jppinto.com/2010/03/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis7-using-url-rewrite-2-0/) might be of some assistance.